# Viewテーブル作成時に参照値がNULLの場合別条件で結合を行いたい

Tags: mysql, sql

現在Viewテーブルの作成を行っていいます。

下記のようにテーブルデータを結合しているのですが、playerテーブルをhoge2.player1_idがNULLの場合、hoge.player1_idで結合したいと考えております。

```
CREATE VIEW hoge_view AS SELECT
 hoge.id,
 hoge.hoge_id,
 hoge2.game_id,
 games.game_category,
 games.tournament,
 hoge.game_result,
 hoge2.game_result,
 hoge.info,
 hoge2.player0_id,
 hoge2.player1_id,
 hoge2.player2_id,
 player0.status as player0_status,
 player1.status as player1_status,
 player2.status as player2_status,
 player0.name as player0_name,
 player1.name as player1_name,
 player2.name as player2_name,
 player0.first_name as player0_first_name,
 player1.first_name as player1_first_name,
 player2.first_name as player2_first_name,
 player0.team_id as player0_team_id,
 player1.team_id as player1_team_id,
 player2.team_id as player2_team_id,
 games.date
 FROM hoge
 JOIN hoge2
    ON hoge.hoge_id = hoge2.id
 JOIN games
    ON hoge2.game_id = games.id
 JOIN players AS player0
    ON hoge2.player0_id = player0.id
 JOIN players AS player1
    ON hoge2.player1_id = player1.id
 JOIN players AS player2
    ON hoge2.player2_id = player2.id
 JOIN teams AS player1_team
    ON player1_team.id = player1.team_id
 JOIN teams AS player0_team
    ON player0_team.id = player0.team_id
```

以下のようにして作成したところViewテーブルの参照が出来なくなってしまいました。
こちらどのように作成すればよいかご存じでしょうか。
アドバイスなど頂けると大変助かります。

よろしくお願い致します。

```
JOIN player as player1
    ON (hoge2.player1_id = player.id AND hoge2.player1_id IS NOT NULL)
    OR hoge.player1_id = player.id
```

Comment: 対象のテーブルのCreate文とサンプルデータ、また期待する結果の表なんかがあるとより回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: サンプルだとコンパイルエラーおきませんか？playerを複数結合しているのにplayer.idとしてしまったら変です。Viewとテーブルとやりたいことをそのまま記載してください。

Comment: 実際の作成したサンプルに編集いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

> Viewテーブル作成時に参照値がNULLの場合別条件で結合を行いたい

以下の考え方はどうでしょうか？

1. 主テーブルとジョイン先1を結合する
2. 主テーブルとジョイン先2を結合する、ただし「主テーブルとジョイン先1を結合するときの列がNULLである」条件を加える
3. 1)と2)をunionで結ぶ

質問された方のテーブル定義を「結合」の観点で単純化したモデルで試してみました。

【テーブルの定義】

```
MariaDB [work_db]> desc 主テーブル;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| f1    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| f2    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
MariaDB [work_db]> desc ジョイン先1;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| note  | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
MariaDB [work_db]> desc ジョイン先2;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| note  | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

【テーブルのデータ】

```
MariaDB [work_db]> select * from 主テーブル;
+------+------+------+
| id   | f1   | f2   |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 | NULL |
|    3 | NULL |    2 |
|    4 | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+
```

```
MariaDB [work_db]> select * from ジョイン先1;
+------+-------------------------------+
| id   | note                          |
+------+-------------------------------+
|    1 | ジョイン先1のデータ1          |
|    2 | ジョイン先1のデータ2          |
+------+-------------------------------+
```

```
MariaDB [work_db]> select * from ジョイン先2;
+------+-------------------------------+
| id   | note                          |
+------+-------------------------------+
|    1 | ジョイン先2のデータ1          |
|    2 | ジョイン先2のデータ2          |
+------+-------------------------------+
```

【ビューの定義】

```
MariaDB [work_db]> create view ビュー as
    -> select 主テーブル.id id, 主テーブル.f1 f1, 主テーブル.f2 f2, ジョイン先1.note note from 主テーブル join ジョイン先1 on 主テーブル.f1 = ジョイン先1.id
    -> union
    -> select 主テーブル.id id, 主テーブル.f1 f1, 主テーブル.f2 f2, ジョイン先2.note note from 主テーブル join ジョイン先2 on 主テーブル.f2 = ジョイン先2.id where 主テーブル.f1 is null
    -> ;
```

【ビューの検索結果】

```
MariaDB [work_db]> select * from ビュー;
+------+------+------+-------------------------------+
| id   | f1   | f2   | note                          |
+------+------+------+-------------------------------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | ジョイン先1のデータ1          |
|    2 |    2 | NULL | ジョイン先1のデータ2          |
|    3 | NULL |    2 | ジョイン先2のデータ2          |
+------+------+------+-------------------------------+
```